# How to use Predicate with Collection

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, predicate, hibernate-criteria

I have three tables.

1. parent
2. parent_child_mapping
3. child

I want to filter by child name using predicate. I am trying this without passing child name as argument. I want to return the Parent & Child details if child name only "abc". This is my sample code

**Parent entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long parentId;
    
    ....

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "mappingParentId")
    private Collection<ParentChildMapping> parentChildMappingCollection;
}
```

**Parent child mapping entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_child_mapping")
public class ParentChildMapping{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "mapping_id")
    private Long mappingId;
       
    @JoinColumn(name = "mapping_child_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ChildEntity mappingChildId;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "mapping_parent_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ParentEntity mappingParentId;
}
```

**Child entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private Long childId;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "child_name")
    private String childName;
}
```

current implementation logic

```
Child child = new Child(); 
        child.setChildName("abc"); //setting the required child name
        
        ParentChildMapping parentChildMapping = new ParentChildMapping();
        parentChildMapping.setMappingChildId(child); //setting the child to mapping
        
        List<ParentChildMapping> parentChildMappingArray = new ArrayList<>();
        parentChildMappingArray.add(parentChildMapping); //setting mapping to mapping collection
        
        Parent parent =  new Parent();
        parent.setParentChildMappingCollection(parentChildMappingArray); //finally set mapping collection to parent
        
        CriteriaQuery<Parent> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Parent.class);
        Root<Parent> root = criteriaQuery.from(Parent.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root);
        
        List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();  
    
  System.out.println(((List<ParentChildMapping>)parent.getParentChildMappingCollection()).get(0).getMappingChildId().getChildName().trim().toLowerCase()); //abc
    
        //not working, null pointer exception
        predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.<ParentChildMapping>get("parentChildMappingCollection").<ChildEntity>get("mappingChildId").<String>get("childName")), ((List<ParentChildMapping>)parent.getParentChildMappingCollection()).get(0).getMappingChildId().getChildName().trim().toLowerCase()));
    
        criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
```

I want to return the Parent & Child if child name only "abc".

I am trying to implement this

```
  SELECT p.parent_id
  FROM parent p
  JOIN parent_child_mapping pcmap on p.parent_id = pcmap.mapping_parent_id
  JOIN child c on pcmap.mapping_child_id = c.child_id
  WHERE c.child_name = 'abc'
```

I hope you understand this question.

Comment: Did you try to debug it and see where does the NPE occur (and possibly why)? You have so many methods chained in that line, and it's hard to figure out where does the NPE occur.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.parentChildMappingCollection] of basic type
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.illegalDereference(AbstractPathImpl.java:82)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an EXISTS predicate to only return `Parent` if one of the `children` names match. See [How to check if entity in set contains a certain value using criteriaBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570160/how-to-check-if-entity-in-set-contains-a-certain-value-using-criteriabuilder/66580206#66580206) for details.